# MySQL start interactive mode with a script

Tags: terminal, command-line, mysql-cli

How can I start mysql interactive mode from the command line, with a list of commands to run one-by-one at different prompts as if I had typed them?

`printf "use my_db;\nselect * from my_table;\n" | mysql -u root -p` doesn't work, I guess because `mysql` detects it's not running in a tty

And I can't try

```
printf "use my_db;\nselect * from my_table;\n" | script -qfec "mysql -u root -pMyPassword" /dev/null
```

because the docker container I'm in has no `script` command

Comment: MySQL has an option `--init-command` but unfortunately, [it doesn't work](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27885) (that bug has been open since 2007).